# How to define a transfer (activation) function in Matlab Neural Network toolbox properly?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

Let me explain my situation:

There are some pre-defined transfer (activation) functions in Matlab neural network toolbox such as logsig, tansig, pureline, softmax, etc.

These function are stored in **../Matlab Folder/toolbox/nnet/nnet/nntransfer/**.

Each function has a folder with the same name starting with a **+**.

Let's see what we have for **tansig** transfer function:

---

The **apply.m** file contains the code of the forward pass:

```
function a = apply(n,param)
  a = 2 ./ (1 + exp(-2*n)) - 1;
end
```

where, **a** is the layer *output* and **n** is the *weighted input* of the layer.

---

The **da_dn** file contains the definition of the *activation function derivative*:

```
function d = da_dn(n,a,param)
    d = 1-(a.*a);
end
```

where again, **a** is the layer *output* and **n** is the *weighted input* of the layer.

---

For the **backpropagation** process, there are two files that I did not understand completely, but I think they are used to compute incoming and outcoming gradient of the layer respectively:

```
function da = forwardprop(dn,n,a,param)
  da = bsxfun(@times,dn,1-(a.*a));
end
```

---

```
function dn = backprop(da,n,a,param)
 dn = bsxfun(@times,da,1-(a.*a));
end
```

---

My goal is to define a **Vector Normalizing** layer.

So, I changed the aforementioned files in this manner:

```
function a = apply(n,param) % (forward pass) function
 [M,N] = size(n);
 norm = sqrt(sum(n.^2,1)); 
 a = n;
 for i = 1:M
     for j = 1:N
         a(i,j) = n(i,j) / norm(1,j);
     end
 end
 end



 function d = da_dn(n,a,param)
 %VectorNormalizer.DA_DN Input-Output derivative
 [M,N] = size(n);
 d = zeros(M,N);

 Den=sqrt((sum(n.^2,1)).^3); % partial derivatives denominator matrix
 Num=zeros(M,N); % partial derivatives numerator matrix

 inDiag=zeros(1,N); % computing diagonal  elements of numerator matrix (sum of squares of non_diagonal elements in each column) 
 for i=1:M
     for j=1:N
         if (i~=j)
             inDiag(1,j)=inDiag(1,j)+(n(i,j).^2);
         end
     end
 end

outDiag=ones(M,N); % computing non-diagonal  elements of numerator (negative multiplication of each non_diagonal element and diagonal element of each column)
for j=1:N
    outDiag(:,j)=-n(j,j);
end
for i=1:M
    for j=1:N
        if (i~=j)
            outDiag(i,j)=n(i,j)*outDiag(i,j);
        end
    end
end

for i=1:M
    for j=1:N
        if (i==j)
            Num(i,j)=inDiag(1,j);
        else
            Num(i,j)=outDiag(i,j);
        end
        d(i,j)=Num(i,j)/Den(1,j);
    end
end
end % function
```

---

```
function da = forwardprop(dn,n,a,param)
%% I did not find any way to pass "d" here, so I copied "d" computation codes from da_da function into here.
   da = bsxfun(@times,dn,d);
end
```

---

```
function dn = backprop(da,n,a,param)
%% I did not find any way to pass "d" here, so I copied "d" computation codes from da_da function into here.
   dn = bsxfun(@times,da,d);
end
```

Although the network converges well (based on the following training curve) , I cannot reach the predicted result.

[image]

Can you detect any mistake here?

I'm not sure about the functionality of the **forwardprop** and **backward prop** functions.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: Why do you assume there is a mistake?

Comment: @Ander Biguri Thanks for your attention. The output of my network should be separated components of the input image normal vectors. Based on my previous experiments, the network is not able to reconstruct vector normals properly. I check all the possible places for the mistake without finding any sign. This layer definition in the last place of hope. Otherwise, I should restart from the beginning. I am also not sure about the last line of the forwardprop and the backprop functions.

Comment: Hum, not sure if I understand. If the NN converges, then it must be doing rigth what you ask it to do. The problem may be that you are not asking it to do what you think you are.

Comment: Please how did get the neural network toolbox did you pay for it  ?